# need to fetch unique identifier for ledger nano s device using hid library

Tags: haskell, hid, ledger-nano-s

Trying to find some unique identifier for ledger nano s device .

I tried to enumerate the device with System.HIDAPI library in haskell but all ledger nano s devices i have, are giving same serial number as "0001" . i am not sure if ledger nano s devices have some unique identifier or not

```
  d <- liftIO $ openDeviceInfo deviceInfo
  let serialNum = serialNumber deviceInfo
  --let sno = eliminate serialNum
  sno <- getSerialNumberString d
```

Comment: I think this is the wrong place to ask the question.

Comment: ok , could you please point me to right forum ? TIA

Comment: who makes the "ledger nano s" device? That would be the place to go.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion , as these devices are widely used by blockchain programmers and by other people in security related solutions.So i thought it would be a possibility that  someone else would have faced the same issue. And there is always a possibility that i might be using HID library incorrectly, so to me it makes sense to ask question. 
Trying other mediums and writing to manufacturer as well .

Answer (score 1):

No, they do not have a unique identifier exposed in HID API. If you want a unique device id, you will have to make an app and generate/store a random number yourself.

Comment: Yes i got to know about this from ledger support team, there are certain security measures due to which unique identifier are not attached to these devices. 
however i needed unique identifier for some specific reasons in the project, so i stored uuid in the device via APDU commands and mapped the devices against that uuid. It is working fine for me as of now.